# Do i need to do anything to use RestKit 2.0 via Cocoapods in my non-arc project?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

just set up my old project with Cocoapods, and now i'm trying out restkit.
I have everything up and running, it deploys and runs fine. When i analyze the app i don't see any strange leaks from what i can see.

However, i just noticed that RestKit is ARC in 2.0. My project is currently non-arc, for a number of reasons.

I have a couple of files that i ARC through the "-fobjc-arc"-flag, however, I can't see how i would do that with a pod.

I'm kind of a beginner with cocoapods, so i'm wondering if i need to/can do anything? The documentation i've seen is old and mostly deals with including non-arc in an arc project.

Would be great with some input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need to do anything. The `podspec` defined by RestKit tells Cocoapods that it is an ARC library, so it'll handle the correct build settings during the install/project setup for you.

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/development/RestKit.podspec

`s.requires_arc = true`

Comment: Thanks, mate, what i was hoping for. :)